# TWRP mode devices unauthorized

Tags: adb

I wipe my phone system in TWRP mode before I transfer new rom file to sdcard.
Now I cant use adb push cmd because of the devices is unauthorized

Anyone know how to authorized it in TWRP mode?

Thanks very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved**

For anyone who meet this issue, just use TWRP sideload feature
When open this feature the devices is list as sideload mode

**➜  ROM adb devices**
**List of devices attached

D01EB0A014660Q99        sideload**

and now you can flash it with

**➜  ROM adb sideload RR-N-v5.8.3-20170623-thor-Unofficial.zip**

Comment: Note that this is not a full-blown `adb` support but allows you to install the ROM. I used MTP mount option to transfer the ROM image on the internal memory instead. Still looking for information about how to really enable `adb shell` support in TWRP. Removing `adb` support from TWRP is not a security feature when one can pass ANY binary to run using `fastboot boot filename.img`.